# Canon i-Sensys LBP5000 driver on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, print-drivers

I downloaded the driver for the Canon LPB5000 laser printer from Canon, but it isn't working.

It seems to be online, but it shows that USB cable is not connected.

I have uninstalled every printer driver on my computer and also disabled anti-virus protection and firewall.

Canon says the printer is too old for Windows 10.

Comment: First, turn your anti-virus software and firewall back on. There is not a valid reason to then them off. Second, if this is a USB printer what happened when you just plugged the printer into the computer? Microsoft may have a compatible generic driver that will work. Finally, the only other option is that a different driver will support the printer on Windows 10. Try manually choosing another Canon laser printer driver from Windows' list of drivers and see if those will work. If they don't you may simply be out of luck.

Comment: Add this info to your question: where did you download drivers (official website states Win 10 compatibility), did you install them while printer was connected and did you try restarting PC before testing?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot run the printer from Windows 10, you **can try to** use it from Ubuntu or other Linux distro. You can test this without needing to install Ubuntu by creating a bootable USB drive with *persistent* storage.

- First, there was no reason to disable AV and firewall, and you have invited damage to your system, and loss of personal data. Make sure both are working.
- Using USB flash drive of 16 GB or more, install [live Ubuntu with *persistence*](https://www.howtogeek.com/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) (or other OS). Be aware that running from an OS on flash drive may be exceedingly slow, but this is just to test the efficacy of the printer driver.
- Boot from USB, [download the correct driver from Canon](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp5000.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)) and install the [Canon i-SENSYS LBP5000 driver](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/03/10/printer-canon-i-sensys-lbp5000-ubuntu-driver-how-to-download-install/) in the OS on the USB.

If you can print successfully from Ubuntu, you have a few choices:

- Install Ubuntu as a virtual machine (VM) in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), or in [a third-party VM](https://techsviewer.com/best-free-virtual-machine-software-2018/). That would allow creating a document in Windows 10 and *immediately* switching to Linux to print.
- Install Ubuntu for dual-booting on the internal drive. That would require shifting between operating systems, rather a nuisance.
- If you like Ubuntu, and have all the applications you need running on it, you could replace Windows OS.
- Continue running from the USB drive with persistent Ubuntu. If it runs too slowly, you could experiment with installing live persistent Ubuntu on an external drive, SSD or HDD. **N.B.** some PC's may not be able to boot from SSD.

Note that, though you *could* run an older version of Windows (e.g., XP or 7) in WSL, Microsoft no longer supports those operating systems.